# How to intent to Location Mode Settings in Android?

Tags: android, android-location, android-settings

I know that I can use the following code to go to the Location Settings and then to Location Mode:

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

But is it possible to go to Location Mode/Locating Method directly

Locating Method image

[image]

Comment: hello gps is must required for your application ??

Comment: i think you no need to redirect user to setting you can do that programatically too :)

Comment: Yeap, it is a must in my application, but now I am also curious about how can I do that programmatically?

Comment: ok but that will ask user to enable gps then user just tap ok then its automatically on with high accuracy. no need to redirect to setting that's fine ?

Comment: you can get both click ok and discard in dialogue so that's enough for your application or not ??

Comment: I wanted user to be able to change to "Battery Saving" option.

Comment: what about location setting ??

Comment: I think Subhash is referencing the thing Google apps have with an OK box to enable gps but that both requires a Google Play API key and only works for switching to gps+network providers and so is not useful.  I am struggling with this myself as my phone has a broken GPS antenna but network provider works fine.   I've been wracking my brain over how to set network-only provider most easily but there appears to be nothing that can be done without building your own ROM.  The setting can not be edited by user space apps and the Intent can only go to overall location settings not the mode picker.

Comment: UTS app does this so it is possible, If you have found solution please post here...https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cris.utsmobile